# Conditionally adding multiple rows (SQL SERVER 2008)

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert-update

I need to add multiple rows in a table at once. Those rows have some field values in common.
I solved my problem using a cursor and this is the stored proc.

Does anyone have a better way of doing it?

```
    USE [MyDataBase]
    GO


    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAddDetailsBatch]
    (
    @IdOperTur UniqueIdentifier,
    @IdProd UniqueIdentifier,
    @Model Bit,
    @PrAd Decimal(18,2),
    @PrMe Decimal(18,2),
    @PoCo Decimal(5,2)
    )
    AS
    DECLARE @prpr_Id UniqueIdentifier
    DECLARE @IdCont UniqueIdentifier = NULL

    DECLARE CPr CURSOR FOR SELECT prpr_Id FROM trsx_PrPr WHERE (prod_Id = @IdProd)
    OPEN CPr

    FETCH NEXT FROM CPr INTO @prpr_Id
    WHILE @@Fetch_Status=0 BEGIN /*iterate through all records from cursor*/

     SET @IdCont = (SELECT cont_Id FROM trsx_Cont
                    WHERE  (prpr_Id = @prpr_Id) AND (optu_Id = @IdOperTur))

     IF @IdCont IS NULL
     BEGIN
      INSERT INTO trsx_Cont(cont_Id, prpr_Id, optu_Id, cont_Neto, cont_PrAd, cont_PrMe, cont_PoCo)
      VALUES (NEWID(), @prpr_Id, @IdOperTur, @Model, @PrAd, @PrMe, @PoCo)
     END

     FETCH NEXT FROM CPr INTO @prpr_Id
    END
   CLOSE CPr
   DEALLOCATE CPr
   RETURN
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
insert into trsx_Cont(cont_Id, prpr_id, optu_Id, cont_Neto, cont_PrAd, cont_PrMe, cont_PoCo)
select (newid(), trsx_PrPr.prpr_id, @IdOperTur, @Model, @PrAd, @PrMe, @PoCo)
from trsx_PrPr
where not exists(
    SELECT 1
    from trsx_Cont
    WHERE
        trsx_Cont.prpr_Id = trsx_PrPr.prpr_Id AND 
        trsx_Cont.optu_Id = @IdOperTur
) and
trsx_PrPr.prod_id = @IdProd
```

I haven't tested this, and since it's a little complex it may well not work as is, but you should be able to get the idea.

Comment: Wow!!!! First of all, IT WORKED!!! THANKS A LOT. Just a few comments: When I saw your code I thought it will not iterate through, obviously I was wrong. I had to delete the () in the SELECT clause because of syntax and binding errors. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, my bad on the () on for the select - I should have noticed that. ;)